# C# - Get COM Ports with their friendly name using WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm developing a C# solution and I want to get the COM Ports, the description and the friendlyName (if they are bluetooth).

After investigating a bit, I've found that I can get the COM Ports using **WMI/CIMV2/Win32_PnPEntity** by searching the **Name** and **Description** values.

To find the friendly name I need to search on **Win32_PnPSignedDriver** and take the value of **FriendlyName**

Is there a way to match them to get a list like this?

- COM56 - Bluetooth device - MyBTHDeviceName1
- COM76 - Bluetooth device - MyBTHDeviceName2
- COM5 - Serial device -

I attach the code that I have right now to get the first two fields.

```
// Method to retrieve the list of all COM ports.
        public static List<PortInfo> FindComPorts()
        {
            List<PortInfo> portList = new List<PortInfo>();
            ConnectionOptions options = PrepareOptions();
            ManagementScope scope = PrepareScope(Environment.MachineName, options, @"\root\CIMV2");

            // Prepare the query and searcher objects.
            ObjectQuery objectQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0");
            ManagementObjectSearcher portSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, objectQuery);

            using (portSearcher)
            {
                string caption = null;
                // Invoke the searcher and search through each management object for a COM port.
                foreach (ManagementObject currentObject in portSearcher.Get())
                {
                    if (currentObject != null)
                    {
                        object currentObjectCaption = currentObject["Caption"];
                        if (currentObjectCaption != null)
                        {
                            caption = currentObjectCaption.ToString();
                            if (caption.Contains("(COM"))
                            {
                                PortInfo portInfo = new PortInfo();
                                portInfo.Name = caption.Substring(caption.LastIndexOf("(COM")).Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty);
                                portInfo.Description = caption;
                                portList.Add(portInfo);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return portList;
        }
```

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Consider Win32_SerialPort, Description property.

Comment: This helped a lot. I found out about Win32_SerialPort on my own, then I noticed Hans Passant already hinted at it.
I updated the query to
    'Select DeviceID from Win32_SerialPort'
which in my case on my system yields COM3 which is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "friendly name" you are looking for is only suitable when COM Ports are virtual (as I assume they are on your example). I think that you can just get the information you need looking for the `name` property on `Win32_PnPEntity` class. There is no need to search for aditional information on COM ports as you will get all information already on `Win32_PnPEntity` class.

You can also try using [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) and using strong typed objects for that.